# Java library to break up a big polygon into many parts

Tags: geotools, jts-topology-suite

I need to break up large polygons like [these](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/caseStudy_largePolyValidation.htm#download) into smaller manageable pieces that can be stored in my DB. I tried searching for tools to do this and mostly come across using software such as ArcGIS or QGIS. Is there no support for this in JTS or Geotools? I need to do this in a java program. As this is a complex task, I would much prefer to use a high quality tested and tried library rather than develop my own code to do this. My requirement is that if I have a JTS geometry that is more than 1MB when serialized into WKB, I need a method which can split it into multiple geometries each no bigger than 1MB. Other than that I have no constraint.

Comment: would this help? - http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/polygon-triangulation-via-ear-clipping.html if so I have code somewhere I can dig up

Answer (score 5):

JTS saved the day! I wrote my own subroutine to do this by recursively subdividing a big geometry into pieces until each piece is less than a user-specified size. It goes like this:

```
public static Collection<Geometry> split(Geometry g, int maxSize, int maxPieces)
    {
        if (maxSize < 1000)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxSize should be greater than or equal to 1000");
        }
        if (maxPieces <= 1)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxPieces should be greater than 1");
        }
        ArrayList<Geometry> answer = new ArrayList<Geometry>();
        Queue<Geometry> queue = new LinkedList<Geometry>();
        queue.add(g);
        while (!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            Geometry geom = queue.remove();
            if (size(geom) > maxSize)
            {
                for(Geometry part: subdivide(geom))
                {
                    queue.add(part);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                answer.add(geom);
            }
            if (queue.size() + answer.size() > maxPieces)
            {
                String message = String.format("Exceeded maximum number of allowed subdivisions. Giving up. Consider \n" +
                        "increasing the maxSize and re-running");
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

The key methods which made it possible are `getEnvelope` and `intersection` on the JTS [`Geometry`](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html) object. Here are my results.

Original Geometry ([polyA](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/caseStudy_largePolyValidation.htm)):
[image]

After breaking it up:
[image]

Another Example [PolyB](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/caseStudy_largePolyValidation.htm):

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Hi morpheus,  size & subdivide functions are missing. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: that was left as exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Not cool morpheus, this is a place to share, it would be great if post those functions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation, of the code above. It is in Scala but will be easy to port:

```
@tailrec def divide(pieces: Int, splitFeatures: Seq[Geometry]): Seq[Geometry] = {
  @tailrec def safeIntersection(g1: Geometry, g2: Geometry, buffer: Double = 0.0): Geometry = {
    try {
      g1.intersection(g2)
    } catch {
      case _: TopologyException =>
        safeIntersection(g1.buffer(buffer), g2.buffer(buffer), buffer + 1.0)
    }
  }

  if (splitFeatures.size >= pieces) return splitFeatures.take(number)
  val g = splitFeatures.head
  val bb = g.getEnvelopeInternal
  val newGeometries = Seq(
    new Envelope(bb.getMinX, bb.centre().x, bb.getMinY, bb.centre().y),
    new Envelope(bb.centre().x, bb.getMaxX, bb.getMinY, bb.centre().y),
    new Envelope(bb.getMinX, bb.centre().x, bb.centre().y, bb.getMaxY),
    new Envelope(bb.centre().x, bb.getMaxX, bb.centre().y, bb.getMaxY)
  ).map(GeometryUtil.envelopeToPolygon)
    .map(e => safeIntersection(g, e))
    .filter(!_.isEmpty)

  divide(number, splitFeatures.drop(1) ++ newGeometries)
}

divide(number, Seq(taz.geometry))
```

Answer (score -1):

I implement an solution maybe can help you. It's not so good like morpheus. https://github.com/DiegoQuirinoS/GridGeom. If works for you give some feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer. Posting a link to a solution on another site is not an answer.